# Can I set targetSdkVersion to less than minSdkVersion?

Tags: android, target-sdk, android-min-sdk

I need features from Android API-level 11 but if I set targetSdkVersion to 10 then I get the old-style menus that I want (with the menu button). Are these values "legal" to set, or does targetSdkVersion have to be higher or equal to minSdkVersion?

(Note: It seems to work!)

Comment: `minSdkVersion` sets the minimum compatibility API Level, while `targetSdkVersion` sets the "compile with" API Level. Mi suggestion is to use as minimumSdkVersion the same or lower version than the targetSdkVersion. Add the support library, if required.

Answer (score 4):

As the [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) says about the `android:targetSdkVersion`,

> An integer designating the API Level that the application targets. If
>   not set, the default value equals that given to minSdkVersion. This
>   attribute informs the system that you have tested against the target
>   version and the system should not enable any compatibility behaviors
>   to maintain your app's forward-compatibility with the target version.
>   The application is still able to run on older versions (down to
>   minSdkVersion).

In anycase,`targetSdkVersion` should always be greater than or equal to the `minSdkVersion`, because in no way can your app run below `minSdkVersion`. If you have put `targetSdkVersion` less than the `minSdkVersion` that means you are telling the android system that you have tested this app on the `targetSdkVersion`, but this is not possible (since your app can run on devices only as low as `minSdkVersion`).

Hence by contradiction `targetSdkVersion` should always be greater than equal to the `minSdkVersion`.

Comment: But I have set targetSdkVersion=10 and minSdkVersion=11 and it works. I believe that I can't install it on 10, but I can run it as 10 on sdk>=11.

Comment: What if I'd like to disable security limitations imposed when the target SDK is >= to some value...? I could set it to 1 and have the minimum as what it must be. Would any errors arise somewhere? Or nothing will complain about it? (Note: I know Play Store doesn't allow target SDK below some values, but it would be a release outside Play Store)

Answer (score 0):

Always make the `targetSdkVersion` greater than equal to the `minSdkVersion`.

You can bypass the `android:targetSdkVersion` version and use feature for a specific API level. Best way to solve the issue would be programatically determine the device version at runtime and go for the API specific implementation rather than specifying a hard coded value.

See here,

```
  // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // set the new menu styles
    } else {
      // do nothing and it will show the default theme
}
```

Check the official documentation here,

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html#version-codes